# How to search for a wpf list box item value and highlight the index based on the value?

Tags: wpf, listbox

In my application I would like you highlight an index based on the value. for example:

```
ArrayList itemsList = new ArrayList();
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{      
    itemsList.Add("Coffie");
    itemsList.Add("Tea");
    itemsList.Add("Orange Juice");
    itemsList.Add("Milk");
    itemsList.Add("Mango Shake");
    itemsList.Add("Iced Tea");
    itemsList.Add("Soda");
    itemsList.Add("Water");

    listBox.ItemsSource = itemsList;
    ApplyDataBinding();       
}

private void ApplyDataBinding()
{
    listBox.ItemsSource = null;
    listBox.ItemsSource = itemsList;
}
```

It does not matter where in the listbox "Orange Juice" is I would like to highlight it based on its value. If the Position change it should be still highlighted. (Not based on the selected index)

Comment: listBox.SelectedValue = "Orange Juice"; ?

Comment: @Anton Danylov not the selected value using a mouse click or anarrow. I want to give a  background colour weather "Orange Juice" is selected or not...So I would like to highlight "Orange Juice" constantly  even if something else is selected!! and when the position changed it is still highlighted

Comment: Added an answer with minimal code changes to achieve desired outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to highlight an item based on it's value, then you need to define your own datatemplate for an item and use a converter to provide appropriate brush for the background. Something like that:

[image: results]

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:TextToBrushConverter x:Key="TextToBrushConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListBox Name="listBox" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Background="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource TextToBrushConverter}}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Converter

```
class TextToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((value as String) == "Orange Juice")
        {
            return Brushes.Orange;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: The events Only triggers on form load is there a way of triggering the event constantly/ during run time..dynamical so if I change "Orange juice"  to Soda?

Comment: I'd suggest to stick to MVVM pattern, where your list items would be object of class implementing INotifyPropertyChanged interface, with Name and Background properties. In other case you may still call your ApplyDataBinding() method to trigger TextToBrushConverter.Convert method. In Convert method you may implement logic that selects background color.

Comment: Or you may call CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(itemsList).Refresh() that also will requery Convert method.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you place the items into a class, *think Object Oriented design* and then work off of properties (as flags) to give different states.

Then by using Xaml styles to key off those different properties to achieve the affect you are looking for.

---

Say for example we have an `Order` class with these properties

```
public class Order
{
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public bool InProgress { get; set; }
}
```

When an order is marked as in progress (`InProgress` = `true`) we want to show red in our list box say for "Alpha" and "Omega" which are in progress:

[image]

**ListBox Xaml**

Here is the Xaml which binds to our data (how you bind is up to you) and shows how to work with [Style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style(v=vs.110).aspx)(s), [DataTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate(v=vs.110).aspx), and [DataTrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Windows.DataTrigger);k(VS.XamlEditor);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5)&rd=true)(s) to achieve that:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource Orders}"
         x:Name="lbOrders">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:Order}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CustomerName}" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=InProgress}"
                             Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground"
                            Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

Here is the data setup in the pages's resource Xaml to do that, but it could be created in code behind:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <model:Orders x:Key="Orders">
        <model:Order CustomerName="Alpha"
                        OrderId="997"
                        InProgress="True" />
        <model:Order CustomerName="Beta"
                        OrderId="998"
                        InProgress="False" />
        <model:Order CustomerName="Omega"
                        OrderId="999"
                        InProgress="True" />
        <model:Order CustomerName="Zeta"
                        OrderId="1000"
                        InProgress="False" />
    </model:Orders>
</Window.Resources>
```

---

This should give you enough to start on and create a full featured UI.